# Есть 2 массива нужно перемножить их значения по номеру ячейки

Tags: objective-c, swift3

```
let cuont = [1,2,1,1,2]

let price = [20.00,10.00,55.00,40.00,36.00]
```

Пример:

```
1*20.00+2*10+1*55.00+1*40+2*36.00
```

Comment: и что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: нет не получилось

Comment: Вы поймите здесь за вас решать не будут, без ваших попыток решить задачу самостоятельно!

Comment: задача более глубже чем кажется, мне тупо нужно понять как перемножитть 2 массива, решение меня не интересует интересует идея

Comment: Как? так как у вас в примере? Создаете `for i` по первому массиву, перемножая `i-й` элемент первого масива на `i-й` элемент второго масива можете сразу вывести на екран можете сохранить в теритий масив

Comment: а как создать конструкцию для двух массивов в одном цикле

Comment: let count = [1,2,2,1]
let price = [20.0,30.0,10.0,5.0]
for (_, value) in (count.enumerated()) {
    print(value)
}

Comment: не `for each` а `for i`!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю зачем это нужно, но можно использовать пронумерованный массив для этих целей:

```
let count: [Double] = [1,2,1,1,2]
let price: [Double] = [20.00,10.00,55.00,40.00,36.00]

count.enumerated().forEach({
    if price.count <= $0.offset { return }
    print($0.element * price[$0.offset])
})
```

Comment: уже сделал ! но спасибо за ответ